# Easy task with sector's area.

Tags: integration

I'm trying to calculate the area of sector bounded by the polar curve
$\theta = r \arctan(r)$, from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = \pi / \sqrt3$ .
I tried to parametrise this, but the integral will very difficult.

Is there a general way to calculate an area bounded by the curve $\theta = \theta(r)$? Not $r = r(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just go for it?
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\sqrt3}\int_0^{r\tan^{-1}r}r\,d\theta\,dr&=\int_0^{\sqrt3}r^2\tan^{-1}r\,dr\\
&=\left.\frac13r^3\tan^{-1}r\right|_0^{\sqrt3}-\frac13\int_0^{\sqrt3}\frac{r^3}{1+r^2}dr\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}-\frac13\int_0^{\sqrt3}\left(r-\frac r{1+r^2}\right)dr\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}-\frac16\left[r^2-\ln(1+r^2)\right]_0^{\sqrt3}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}-\frac16\left[3-\ln(4)\right]=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt3}-\frac12+\frac13\ln(2)\end{align}$$